# How to migrate from Sharepoint 2013 classic mode authentication to O365 claims Mode authentication?

Tags: sharepoint-online, claims-based-auth

I have a requirement to migrate from Sharepoint 2013 Classic mode authentication to o365 claims based authentication.

But there is a catch. I need to do it *one subsite at a time* and not the entire application in one go.

Thanks, 
Sheldon

Comment: how you migrating the content to office 365?

Comment: If you're migrating the content, yeah there is no need to do any classic to claims conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods ([MigrateUsersToClaims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj168297.aspx), deprecated [MigrateUsers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554321.aspx)) which are called by your PowerShell-commands ([Convert-SPWebApplication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219696.aspx)). All of these methods are scoped at a WebApplication Level.

With the given Information my answer is: It is not possible to convert a SiteCollection/SubSite/List/Item. You must do it at the WebApplication level.

Could you please provide more information abount why you need to migrate *one subsite at a time*? Maybe your doubts are unnecessary or we can provide a workaround for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are planning to migrate at a Site collection or at site level because the migration process is taking up a lot of time (An average of a few couple of days).

Comment: Entire farm migration that is.

Comment: If you say "migration process" you mean the classic to claims migration? Or the O365 migration? As Waqas and Trevor already mentioned, your migration-plan would be useful. Chances are good that you can skip the entire process of classic-to-claims. The more information you provide, the better we can help.

Comment: We used the Convert-SPWebApplication command to migrate the classic mode authentication to claims based authentication on the existing SharePoint 2013 on premises itself and then thought of migrating the upgraded farm to o365 directly. But the volume of the farm is around 1 TB and hence the powershell command went on running for 5-6 days and we had to force stop.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "migrating the upgraded farm to o365 DIRECTLY"? There is no database-attach method like when you migrate from SP2010 or SP2013 to a newer version.